# Is it possible to create an RDS instance in different Region using Terraform (using snapshot of original DB)

Tags: amazon-rds, terraform-provider-aws, terraform-aws-modules

I have my production site in us-east-1 region whereas the DR site in us-east-2 region.

We are using terraform to configure the environment but now stuck at the DB part.

1. We want to copy the snapshots of our DB from us-east-1 region to the us-east-2 region using terraform.
2. We want to create RDS instance using this copied snapshot in us-east-2 region.

Ultimate Goal --> To create a database in us-east-2 region using a snapshot which is available in us-east-1 region, and all this should be done using terraform.

Comment: is the snapshot encrypted? are they in the same account?

Comment: @HumayunM, yes the snapshot is encrypted and they are in the same account.

Answer (score 0):

I have not used the following one to cross-region copy but you could use the following.

**aws_backup_plan** [link1](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-aws/issues/11589) This is to setup backup and used to cross-region copy

**aws_db_instance** [link2](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/db_instance) This can be used to create the RDS instance.